# Computing the homology groups of spaces in a fibration

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibration, homology, spectral-sequences

Let $F\rightarrow X\rightarrow B$ be a fibration. If we know very well the spaces $F$ and $B$ and wish to compute the homology of $X$. One possible tool is the Serre Spectral Sequence. However, it works under the condition that $\pi_1(B)$ acts trivially on $H_*(F;G)$. If this condition ($\pi_1(B)$ acts trivially on $H_*(F;G)$) does not hold, what other tools can one use to compute the homology of the homology of $X$?

In fact I am interested in the special case that all spaces in the fibration are $K(\pi,1)$ spaces. If any approach works for this particular case it would be wonderful.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you can still use the Serre spectral sequence but you need to use local coefficients.
 

Comment: As Callan mentions, there is a Serre spectral sequence for any fibration (and a Leray spectral sequence for any map).  It's a little more complicated technically due to the local coefficients but it's perfectly usable.  For this Serre spectral sequence, it's not enough to know $H_*(B)$ and $H_*(F)$ independently, but you have to know $H_*(B; H_*(F))$, homology in the twisted system. 

Comment: @Ryan, May I know where I can find any reference on the Serre Spectral sequence for any fibration mentioned in your comment? Thank you!

Comment: Spanier's book.  Also Whitehead's book.  And I'm pretty sure Peter May's "Concise Course".   If you're familiar with the set-up of the Serre spectral sequence when $\pi_1$ acts trivially on $H_* F$, you'll notice the argument is essentially the same but with the twisted coefficients, if $\pi_1$ does not act trivially on $H_* F$.   

Comment: In the case where all spaces are $K(\pi,1)$'s this is called the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre SS and can be found in any book on group (co)homology. Knowing this doesn't aid your computations though...


Comment: There's a nice treatment of the general case in Davis-Kirk Lectures Notes in Algebraic Topology, as well as a chapter on local coefficients if you need brushing up on that.

Comment: @GregFriedman Hi Could you tell which part of this book can I find the relating material?

Comment: I don't have the book handy right now, but you should be able to find it in the table of contents or index by looking for Serre spectral sequence, or perhaps Leray-Serre.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Repeating Mark Grant's comment, the spectral sequence when all spaces are $K(\pi,1)$s goes under the name Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence.

Good references for this spectral sequence are:

D. Benson: Representations and Cohomology II: cohomology of groups and modules

L. Evens: The cohomology of groups

Loads of papers have been written about this spectral sequence: Calculating $E^2$, when it degenerates at $E^2$, differentials, extension problems, you name it.... But a lot of the details depend on which class of groups $\pi$ you are interested in, so it's hard to give specific pointers without more information.